# Changing display after animation

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change an element's display to none after a CSS transition. This is because I want elements below the removed to move up (or down) to take the removed element's place. The transition is working, but it doesn't change the display.

```
.glossary-item {
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid;
    opacity: 1;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.transition.hidden {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
}

.transition {
    transition: opacity 1s ease;
}
```

```
<input type="text" id="glossaryFilter" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search..">

<div id="glossary-container">
    <div class="glossary-item">
        <div class="glossary-body">
            <h5 class="glossary-title">Title</h5>
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="glossary-item">
        <div class="glossary-body">
            <h5 class="glossary-title">Other</h5>
            <p>Stuff</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, cards, cardContainer, h5, title, i;
    input = document.getElementById("glossaryFilter");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    cardContainer = document.getElementById("glossary-container");
    cards = cardContainer.getElementsByClassName("glossary-item");
    for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        title = cards[i].querySelector(".glossary-body h5.glossary-title");
        if (title.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            cards[i].classList.add('transition');
            cards[i].classList.remove('hidden');
        } else {
            cards[i].classList.add('transition');
            cards[i].classList.add('hidden');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the class:

```css
displayNone{
    display: none;
}
```

some js:

```js
const afterAnimate = (()=>{
   setTimeout(()=>{
//change "elem" to the fitting element
       elem.classList.add("displayNone");
   }, 1000);
})

//add the function-call to your event which triggers the animation
afterAnimate();
```

Comment: Hm... => made some changes. My aproach is to trigger the class change when you triggered your event after an set timeout. Maybe i didnt understood correctly where your animation gets triggered... have you thought about hoisting? maybe there is a more trivial bug I just dot see in my code - i could not run it.